# Marker not showing in osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I want to add a draggable marker to osmdroid.
for that I use this code

```
    import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;

    Marker marker=new Marker(mapView);
    marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(36.607007, 59.133225));
    marker.setIcon(drawable);
    marker.setImage(drawable);
    marker.setTitle("dddd");  
    marker.showInfoWindow();
```

it dosent show my icon in mapview but just show info window.
can anyone help me about that?

Comment: is your drawable correct? I mean not null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add marker to `Overlays` and `invalidate` your mapView.

Try with adding marker to Map Overlays and calling `mapView.invalidate()` like below.

```
Marker marker=new Marker(mapView);
marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(36.607007, 59.133225));
marker.setIcon(drawable);
marker.setImage(drawable);
marker.setTitle("dddd");  
marker.showInfoWindow();
mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
mapView.invalidate();
```